# NanoPi M4 - RK3399: Apache2 + SSL: Large download hangs

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, openssl, armbian, arm64

I've a brand new setup of Apache2 running under Debian 9 (armbian on NanoPi M4). **Everything works fine until I try to download a large file over HTTPS**. Small files download successfully however, larger ones seem to fail randomly at some point.
**I can't reproduce this issue with plain HTTP**. Example on `wget` (same behaviour on a browser):

```
wget https://xyz---/test.bin --no-check-certificate
--2019-01-13 18:22:22--  https://xyz---/test.bin
Resolving xyz--- (xyz---)... 85.241.xxx.xxx
Connecting to xyz--- (xyz---)|85.241.xxx.xxx|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify xyz---'s certificate, issued by 'CN=Let\'s Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let\'s Encrypt,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1073741824 (1,0G) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'test.bin.2'

test.bin.2                      39%[==================>                               ] 403,66M  11,6MB/s    eta 54s
```

It was downloading fine until it reached 403,66M, after this point nothing else happened. On the server side (`error.log`) I get this:

```
ssl_engine_io.c(2135): [client 85.243.xxx.xxx:59904] OpenSSL: write 16413/16413 bytes to BIO#5588cd8c50 [mem: 5588a87c23] (BIO dump follows)
core_filters.c(525): [client 85.243.xxx.xxx:59904] core_output_filter: flushing because of THRESHOLD_MAX_BUFFER
core_filters.c(547): (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 85.243.xxx.xxx:59904] core_output_filter: writing data to the network
ssl_engine_io.c(2144): [client 85.243.xxx.xxx:59904] OpenSSL: I/O error, 16413 bytes expected to write on BIO#5588cd8c50 [mem: 5588a87c23]
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 85.243.xxx.xxx:59904] AH01993: SSL output filter write failed.
```

It seems to run the `core_output_filter: flushing because of THRESHOLD_MAX_BUFFER` and then nothing else happens. Sometimes I've also noticed this error:

```
ssl_engine_io.c(2135): [client 95.239.xxx.xxx:9937] OpenSSL: write 45/45 bytes to BIO#55bd9e23e0 [mem: 55bd9ec213] (BIO dump follows)
ssl_engine_io.c(2144): [client 95.239.xxx.xxx:9937] OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#55bd9e9d80 [mem: 55bd9ec213]
```

Here is the configuration of the VHosts serving this requests:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xyz---
    ServerAdmin tcb13---
    DocumentRoot /test
    ErrorLog /test/error.log
    CustomLog /test/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /mnt/SU1/letsencrypt/config/live/xyz---/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /mnt/SU1/letsencrypt/config/live/xyz---/privkey.pem
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"

    LogLevel trace6
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm sure this isn't a network related problem because:

1. Only happens with SSL enabled, on non-ssl vhosts I can download without issues;
2. Other protocols (FTP and SCP) work just fine to download the same test file;
3. No issues while testing the network with iperf3.

**Some system information**:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:        9.6
Codename:       stretch

uname -a
Linux testxyz 4.4.162-rk3399 #41 SMP Fri Oct 26 14:03:47 CEST 2018 aarch64 GNU/Linux

apache2ctl -V | grep -i "Server version"
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
root@testxyz:~# dpkg -l |grep apache2
ii  apache2                         2.4.25-3+deb9u6                                       arm64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                     2.4.25-3+deb9u6                                       arm64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apache2-data                    2.4.25-3+deb9u6                                       all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
ii  apache2-utils                   2.4.25-3+deb9u6                                       arm64        Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers)
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.3           7.3.0-2+0~20181217092659.24+stretch~1.gbp54e52f       arm64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88235/discussion-on-question-by-tcb13-apache2-ssl-large-download-hangs).

Comment: Update: looks like a network issue on my device. I just added an USB 3 to Ethernet adaptor I don't have the issues above while using that network interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to find out that this **issue** is related to the **integrated Ethernet and known issues with the RK3399 CPU**. With an USB 3 to Ethernet adapter this issue won't happen.

> The boards like RK3399 need TCP/UDP offloading disabled to avoid the
>   retransmissions and reset errors. This was already implemented by
>   Ayufan on Rock64 and RockPro64 Rootfs and DietPi needs this too.

An easy fix for this is to disable offloading:

```
ethtool -K eth0 rx off tx off
```

You may check offloading status afterwards with `ethtool --show-offload eth0`.
After disabling the offloading features I don't have the reported issue anymore.

**In order to survive reboots** (and network restarts) you may create a script at `/etc/network/if-up.d/disable-offload` similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ethtool -K eth0 rx off tx off
```

(Be sure to NOT name the file with .sh and to chmod +x this file as well)